# How exactly does the AudioRecord class work?

Tags: android, audio, wav

Please see my other questions as well because I think they are related:
[Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18393805/is-there-a-significant-delay-in-initializing-audiotrack)
[Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18375508/need-help-understanding-data-section-of-wav-file)
[Question 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18349054/need-to-understad-how-audiorecord-and-audiotrack-work-for-raw-pcm-capture-and-pl)
This is the code I am using which performs a pass through of the audio signals obtained at the mic to the speaker, when I press a buton:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    AudioManager am = null;
    AudioRecord record =null;
    AudioTrack track =null;
    final int SAMPLE_FREQUENCY = 44100;
    final int SIZE_OF_RECORD_ARRAY = 1024;  // 1024 ORIGINAL
    final int WAV_SAMPLE_MULTIPLICATION_FACTOR = 1;
    int i= 0;
    boolean isPlaying = false;
    private volatile boolean keepThreadRunning;
    private RandomAccessFile stateFile, stateFileTemp;
    private File delFile, renFile;
    String stateFileLoc = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath(); 
    class MyThread extends Thread{
        private volatile boolean needsToPassThrough;
        // /*
        MyThread(){
            super();
        }

        MyThread(boolean newPTV){
            this.needsToPassThrough = newPTV;
        }
        // */

        // /*
        @Override
        public void run(){
            // short[] lin = new short[SIZE_OF_RECORD_ARRAY];
            byte[] lin = new byte[SIZE_OF_RECORD_ARRAY];
            int num = 0;
            // /*
            if(needsToPassThrough){
                record.startRecording();
                track.play();
            }
            // */
            while (keepThreadRunning) {
            // while (!isInterrupted()) {
                num = record.read(lin, 0, SIZE_OF_RECORD_ARRAY);
                for(i=0;i<lin.length;i++)
                    lin[i] *= WAV_SAMPLE_MULTIPLICATION_FACTOR; 
                track.write(lin, 0, num);
            }
            // /*
            record.stop();
            track.stop();
            record.release();
            track.release();
            // */
        }
        // */

        // /*
        public void stopThread(){
            keepThreadRunning = false;
        }
        // */
    }

    MyThread newThread;

    private void init() {
        int min = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(SAMPLE_FREQUENCY, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
        record = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_COMMUNICATION, SAMPLE_FREQUENCY, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO,
                                 AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, min);
        int maxJitter = AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(SAMPLE_FREQUENCY, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
        track = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION, SAMPLE_FREQUENCY, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO,
                               AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, maxJitter, AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
        am = (AudioManager) this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        am.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION);

        try {
            stateFile = new RandomAccessFile(stateFileLoc+"/appState.txt", "rwd");
            stateFileTemp = new RandomAccessFile(stateFileLoc+"/appStateTemp.txt", "rwd");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        delFile = new File(stateFileLoc+"/appState.txt");
        renFile = new File(stateFileLoc+"/appStateTemp.txt");

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        // newThread.stopThread();
        Log.d("MYLOG", "onResume() called");
        init();
        keepThreadRunning = true;
        try {
            if(stateFile.readInt() == 1){
                isPlaying = true;
                Log.d("MYLOG", "readInt == 1");
            }
            else{
                isPlaying = false;
                Log.d("MYLOG", "readInt <> 1");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // */


        // newThread = new MyThread(true);
        newThread = new MyThread(isPlaying);
        newThread.start();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
        Log.d("MYLOG", "onPause() called");
        newThread.stopThread();
        // android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
        try {
            if(isPlaying)
                stateFileTemp.writeInt(1);
            else
                stateFileTemp.writeInt(0);

            delFile.delete();

            renFile.renameTo(delFile);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION);
        Log.d("MYLOG","onCreate() called");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        newThread.stopThread();
        // android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
        // killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
        // newThread.interrupt();
        delFile.delete();
         Log.d("MYLOG", "onDestroy() called");
    }

    public void passStop(View view){
        Button playBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);  
        // /*
        if(!isPlaying){
            record.startRecording();
            track.play();
            isPlaying = true;
            playBtn.setText("Pause");
        }
        else{
           record.stop();
           track.pause();
           isPlaying=false;
           playBtn.setText("Pass through");
        }
        // */
    }
```

the files `appState.txt` and `appStateTemp.txt` were added to save whether pass through was being performed when the app last lost focus, but that is probably not very significant here. What I want to know is:

1. What happens when `record.read()` is called without calling `record.startrecording()` ?
2. What is the significance of `SIZE_OF_RECORD_ARRAY`? I thought it should be at least the value returned by `AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize()` but in this program it doesn't affect the output at all even if I set it to 1.
3. If I use 16 bit PCM encoding I need at least a short variable to store the digital equivalent of the audio samples. However in this code even if I change the lin variable from short array to byte array, there is no apparent change in the output. So how does the read function store the digital samples in the array? Does it automatically allocate 2 byte elements for each sample? If that is the case, does it do it as little endian or big endian?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Question 1 and 3 should be easy for you to check with your app, but here goes:

> 1: What happens when record.read() is called without calling record.startrecording() ?

I would expect there to be no flow of data from the underlying audio input stream, and that `read()` therefore returns 0 or possibly an error code, indicating that no data has been read.

---

> 2: What is the significance of SIZE_OF_RECORD_ARRAY? I thought it should be at least the value returned by AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize() but in this program it doesn't affect the output at all even if I set it to 1.

The value of `getMinBufferSize` is important when you specify the buffer size in the call to the `AudioRecord` constructor. What you're changing with `SIZE_OF_RECORD_ARRAY` is just the amount of data you're reading with each call to `read()` - and while it isn't a particularly good idea to call `read()` once per byte (because of the overhead of all those function calls), I can imagine that it still will work.

---

> 3: If I use 16 bit PCM encoding I need at least a short variable to store the digital equivalent of the audio samples. However in this code even if I change the lin variable from short array to byte array, there is no apparent change in the output. So how does the read function store the digital samples in the array? Does it automatically allocate 2 byte elements for each sample? If that is the case, does it do it as little endian or big endian?

The underlying native code always uses the `byte` version. The `short` version is simply a wrapper around the `byte` version. So yes, a pair of bytes will be used for each sample in this case.
As for the endianness; it would be little-endian on the vast majority of Android devices out there.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. Please don't mind but I have another question, is there any good reference to using AudioRecord and AudioTrack classes, that explains everything in detail, for example the part you said about the underlying system always writing in byte form, and the short being just a wrapper? Are there any book chapters or tutorials that explain using AudioTrack and Audiorecord ? Everything material I have been able to find just goes over audio recording and playback superficially, by using the MediaRecorder class

Comment: "SIZE_OF_RECORD_ARRAY is just the amount of data you're reading with each call to read()" this would mean I can have a low value for SIZE_OF_RECORD_ARRAY, but it cannot exceed the buffer size that I used while creating AudioRecord isn't it?

Comment: Q1: None that I know of. I used to work with Android audio at Sony for a few years, and the source was our reference pretty much. Q2: I haven't tried this myself, but I'm pretty sure that you can read more than the specified buffer size and that the call to `read()` simply will block until all the data you want is available (the same way you can write more than the specified buffer size to an `AudioTrack`).

Comment: ok Thank you. One more thing if you don't mind, if I write the `lin` variable (as short or byte) to file using the `RandomAccessFile` class' `write(byte[])` function, it writes a long string of zeros at the beginning of the file. How many zeros is always different, but the string of 0's always ends at a memory offset of xxxxF (from the beginning of the file), never at some random offset like 2dc34. Do you have any idea on why this might be happening?

Comment: I recall that we had problems on some products with "pops" at the beginning of recordings, possibly from the microphone's voltage regulator being enabled. The workaround was to simply return silence for the first X milliseconds of the recording. It's possible that this was a common problem, and that the same kind of workaround was made on a lot of different products.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this I hope will work 100%**

```
  MediaRecorder mRecorder = null;
    String mFileName;
private void startRecording() {

        try {
            mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
            mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
            mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
            mFileName = getRecordDefaultFileName();
            mRecorder.setOutputFile(mFileName);
            mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);

            try {
                mRecorder.prepare();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("prepare() failed");
            }

            mRecorder.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {

            return;
        }

    }

private void stopRecording() {
        try {
            if (mRecorder != null) {
                mRecorder.stop();
                mRecorder.release();
                mRecorder = null;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }

private String getRecordDefaultFileName() {

        File wallpaperDirectory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/" + "recordingFolder" + "/");
        if (!wallpaperDirectory.exists()) {
            wallpaperDirectory.mkdirs();
        }

        return wallpaperDirectory.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "iarecord" + ".3gp";
    }
```

Comment: Not what I'm asking about sorry